# Can not find schedule perspective in pentaho kettle spoon

Tags: pentaho, kettle, perspective, spoon

Hello guys I'm using kettle spoon 5.0.1 and I can't find the Schedule Perspective, or any other except Data Integration Perspective, can you help me, please?

Comment: Are you using the community edition? AFAIK scheduling is part if the enterprise edition...

Comment: Thanks Marco, Yes I'm using the community edition, but in that case how can I schedule my jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need scheduling in CE, you have to do it yourself. Fortunately this isn't terribly hard. Just use an external scheduler to launch transforms and jobs via [Pan](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pan+User+Documentation) and [Kitchen](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation).

For example, I use pgagent since I have PostgreSQL. So I set up my schedules and launch my job as follows:

```
set KETTLE_PASSWORD=Encrypted (Some pwd)
"C:\Program Files\pentaho\Daily_Jobs.bat" > "C:\Program Files\pentaho\Daily_Jobs.log"
```

And then Daily_Jobs.bat is this:

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\pentaho\"
Kitchen.bat /rep:"ETL_PROD" /job:"Daily Jobs" /dir:"/Finished" /user:Brian /level:Basic
```

This runs the job "Daily Jobs" in the "/Finished" directory of my PDI repository as use "Brian" with basic logging and using the password stored in KETTLE_PASSWORD. These are Windows batch files, but .sh scripts in Linux work just as well. No they don't have to be in two separate batch files (I forget why I did that originally).

While I use pgagent, any scheduler that can launch batch files/shell scripts should work.