# Password Encryption for PDI Job

Tags: pentaho, jobs, password-encryption, pdi, spoon

I am creating a batch file to schedule a PDI spoon job.

```
F:\pdi-ce-9.1.0.0-324\data-integration\kitchen.bat /rep:<RepositoryName> /job:ParentJob /dir: /user:<UserName> /pass:<Password> /level:Basic
```

The problem here is we need to provide the password in plain text format which I really want to avoid. I tried `encr -kettle <password>` and then using

```
F:\pdi-ce-9.1.0.0-324\data-integration\kitchen.bat /rep:<RepositoryName> /job:ParentJob /dir: /user:<UserName> /pass:Encrypted <EncyptedPassword> /level:Basic
```

Ref: [Can not find schedule perspective in pentaho kettle spoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349244/can-not-find-schedule-perspective-in-pentaho-kettle-spoon/24371343#24371343)

But it didn't work.

Can anyone please tell me the right way to get it done?

Thanks in advance.